# Prompt choice is not accepted stating its not valid - c# Bot

Tags: c#, botframework, chatbot

Am creating a choice field in my bot and the chosen choice is not accepted.

Below is the screen shot of my error

[image]

[Sample link](https://www.c-sharpcorner.com/article/getting-started-with-customize-a-formflow-using-microsoft-bot-framework/) this is the sample am using for my reference

Code snippet

```
public enum Gender
    {
        [Terms("M","boy")]
         Male,
        [Terms("F","girl")]
         Female

    }
    public Gender? SelectGender;
```

Comment: Can you show your code?

Comment: @RedWei i have edited my answer with code snippet

Comment: The one that you are using, not the one in your link.

Comment: @RedWei i have a similar requirement and so am using choice as in the link. the sample in the link also results with the same error

Comment: What's the change i must do?

Comment: You can add "Male" to terms list, or use regular expression to match user input. For detailed information:"[Match user input using the Terms attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-advanced#match-user-input-using-the-terms-attribute)"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In “[Match user input using the Terms attribute](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/bot-framework/dotnet/bot-builder-dotnet-formflow-advanced#match-user-input-using-the-terms-attribute)”, we can find:

> *By default, the list of terms is generated by applying these steps to the field or value:*
>
> *1. Break on case changes and underscore (_).*
>
> *2. Generate each n-gram up to a maximum length.*
>
> *3. Add "s?" to the end of each word (to support plurals).*

You use the `Terms` attribute to define the list of terms that are used to match user input to a value in a field, which override this default behavior. You do not include **"Male"** in your terms list, so the issue appears when you input Male as value. To solve the issue, you can add Male to your terms list.

```
public enum Gender
{
    [Terms("M", "boy", "Male")]
    Male,
    [Terms("F", "girl", "Female")]
    Female
}
```

Besides, to match more user inputs, you can use regular expression.

Comment: This is working in case of static options. am getting the same error in my dynamic choices.

Comment: @MohanvelV please be explicit in your questions: this answer is correct for what you described, if you have other issues please create a new question or add all the problems related to the same prompt when you ask, and show the code related to the problem

Comment: @NicolasR I have accepted this answer and opened new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/49274275/dynamic-prompt-choice-is-not-accepted-stating-its-not-valid-c-sharp-bot